# Added new bulk action, but only work on bottom dropdown

Tags: bulk

I've added Archived bulk Action to my CPT, but my problem is that everything work fine only if we select the action in the second dropdown.

That's how i've added the new Bulk Action

```
add_action('admin_head', 'add_bulk_action');
function add_bulk_action() {
    global $wp_list_table;
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    if($current_screen->id == 'edit-programmation') {
            $wp_list_table->_actions = array_merge(
            $wp_list_table->get_bulk_actions(),
            array( 'archive' => __( 'Archiver' ) )
        );
    }
}
```

And my custom bulk action verification

```
add_action('load-edit.php', 'custom_bulk_action');
function custom_bulk_action() {
global $typenow;
$post_type = $typenow;

if($post_type == 'programmation') {

    // get the action
    $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');  // depending on your resource type this could be WP_Users_List_Table, WP_Comments_List_Table, etc
    $action = $wp_list_table->current_action();

    /* $action return -1 if I don't choose my action from the bottom dropdown... */

    $allowed_actions = array("archive");
    if(!in_array($action, $allowed_actions)) return;


    // security check
    check_admin_referer('bulk-posts');

    // make sure ids are submitted.  depending on the resource type, this may be 'media' or 'ids'
    if(isset($_REQUEST['post'])) {
        $post_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['post']);
    }

    if(empty($post_ids)) return;

    // this is based on wp-admin/edit.php
    $sendback = remove_query_arg( array('archived', 'untrashed', 'deleted', 'ids'), wp_get_referer() );
    if ( ! $sendback )
        $sendback = admin_url( "edit.php?post_type=$post_type" );

    $pagenum = $wp_list_table->get_pagenum();
    $sendback = add_query_arg( 'paged', $pagenum, $sendback );

    switch($action) {
        case 'archive':

            $archived = 0;
            foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) {

                if ( !perform_archiving($post_id) )
                    wp_die( __('Error while archiving spectacle.') );

                $archived++;
            }
            $sendback = add_query_arg( array('archived' => $archived, 'ids' => join(',', $post_ids) ), $sendback );
            break;

        default: return;
    }

    $sendback = remove_query_arg( array('action', 'action2', 'tags_input', 'post_author', 'comment_status', 'ping_status', '_status',  'post', 'bulk_edit', 'post_view'), $sendback );

    wp_redirect($sendback);
    exit();
}
}
```

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea ?